# Item template doesn't include ListItemID?

Tags: 2013, display-template, content-search-web-part

I have a content search webpart and am using a modified version of the default **Item-Picture3Lines.html** template. The custom parts are to add our own "like" button.

```
<div class="like-icon" data-item-id="_#= itemId =#_" data-item-title="_#= line1 =#_" onclick="javascript:setRating(this);return false;"></div>
```

Basically adding a div and setting some data elements on it. The **itemId** value comes from the default code in the template.

```
var itemId = $getItemValue(ctx, "ListItemID");
```

During the development phase I had used the UI to edit the properties for the CSWP and had put the **ListItemID** into Line 3 of the template just to be sure that when I tried to rate item 85 that I was getting the right item.

And that all worked great.

At the end of development I took ListItemID out of line 3 because the end user doesn't need to see the ID number. But as soon as I did that the whole thing broke.

I'm examining the **ctx.searchResults.ListData.ResultTables** data and none of the returned items include their ListItemID. I thought that was one that was always included.

I've looked at my item template and it includes 'ListItemID':'ListItemID' in the mapped properties.

How do I ensure that ListItemID is returned with my data?